# Register a file association with ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce, file-association

I want to associate a file extension with my ClickOnce application. There is a *File Associations* part in the *Publish options* but I can't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use file associations, your project must conform to a few rules...

- Full Trust is required.
- Must be available "offline".
- Must target 3.5 Framework.

If you are already doing all these things, what, exactly, isn't working?

Comment: In the *File Associations* part, I fill the different parameters (Extention, Description and ProgID) and choose an icon, but when deploying the application, no association is made between the file extension and my program.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the code *inside* the application to handle the file name passed in when the user double-clicks on it and do something with it? You need something like this in your startup.

```
string fileName = string.Empty;
string[] activationData = 
  AppDomain.CurretnDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;
if (activationData != null && activationData.Length > 0)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(activationdata[0]);
    fileName = url.LocalPath.ToString();
}
```

Then you have to add code to do something with the file.